# How to compare between two text and print out the difference in a dict

Tags: python-3.x, compare

Hello people of stackoverflow!

I have a problem where I want to compare between 1 and 2 and I want to see whenever there is a difference between the value `tin` between **1** and **2** then I want to print it out to a dict. (See below example)

The question number one is that how to store those values at the beginning to be able to compare later on?

**1**

```py
{'tin': '00194500874886', 'Amount': 'LOW'}
{'tin': '00523523523574', 'Amount': 'MEDIUM'}
{'tin': '56756756536745', 'Amount': 'NONE'}
{'tin': '00194523575674', 'Amount': 'HIGH'}
{'tin': '51245354536734', 'Amount': 'LOW'}
```

**2**

```py
{'tin': '00194500874886', 'Amount': 'LOW'}
{'tin': '07867867867865', 'Amount': 'MEDIUM'}
{'tin': '55675675756756', 'Amount': 'NONE'}
```

Question two:

As you can see there is some difference between **1** and **2** when it comes to the value of **tin** and I wonder how I can have a output of the difference from the **2** e.g.:

```
{'07867867867865', '55675675756756'}
```

(I just want the differece 2 with 1 and not 1 to 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to Question 1:
you can store these values as list of dictionaries

```
list_1 = [
        {'tin': '00194500874886', 'Amount': 'LOW'},
        {'tin': '00523523523574', 'Amount': 'MEDIUM'},
        {'tin': '56756756536745', 'Amount': 'NONE'},
        {'tin': '00194523575674', 'Amount': 'HIGH'},
        {'tin': '51245354536734', 'Amount': 'LOW'}
    ]

list_2 = [
        {'tin': '00194500874886', 'Amount': 'LOW'},
        {'tin': '07867867867865', 'Amount': 'MEDIUM'},
        {'tin': '55675675756756', 'Amount': 'NONE'}
    ]
```

Answer to Question 2:
you can use list comprehension to find out the difference between list_1 and list_2

```
difference_result = list((item for item in list_2 if item not in list_1))
```

you can not store the difference values like this in a dictionary, because dictionaries are key-value pairs, the below data type is a set

```
{'07867867867865', '55675675756756'}
```

but you can store them as a list of values in a dictionary

```
output_dict = {"difference_values": []}
for value in difference_result:
    output_dict['difference_values'].append(value['tin'])

print(output_dict)
```

results:

```
{'difference_values': ['07867867867865', '55675675756756']}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer! was exactly what I wanted